# Consumption based asset pricing book with Epstein-Zin(-Weil)

Tags: asset-pricing

Any advice for a book covering consumption based asset pricing in general and in particular also covers non-standard asset pricing models / utility functions such as Epstein-Zin(-Weil)?

Besides the obvious 2001 Cochrane - Asset Pricing (which is great but doesn't really give any details about models other than the standard additive power utility model).

Thanks.